# Better approach to get unique data using Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When the user navigates to a unique page (eg /post/1), I want to get the data of the post 1.

To fetch this data, I take the URL pathname with window.location.pathname (that is /post/1), remove first characters (/post/) with substring, and I get 1.

I send this 1 with API and get the post data.

The problem here is window.location.pathname fetches URL pathname very slowly (after page load), and I can't fetch data with API because the URL pathname is "undefined" at first.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: read documents on dynamic routing in nextjs https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#convention,  it might be different if you are using the new app router

Comment: Plus can you show what you have tried so far so we have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Could you show your code, please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### If you are using page directory

you can use `useRouter` hook from nextjs to get the id from the url

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
 
export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()
  // with the assumption that your file structure is `post/[id]`
  return <p>Id: {router.query.id}</p>
}
```

ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#example

### If you are using app directory

it's already embedded to your page props

for this file structure
`post/[id]/page.tsx`

```
export default function Page({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  return <div>Id: {params.id}</div>
}
```

ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#example

Comment: Notice that in this case use the correct dynamic segment parameter instead of id (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#convention)